# Apache2 not working with several subdomains (only one) on Ubuntu 19.04 (Virtual Hosts)

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain

so I have a problem with Apache 2 (2.4.38) virtual hosts. I have set up two of them successfully, one for my actual domain (i. e. example.com) and one for a subdomain (blog.example.com). I then tried creating a new one for yet another subdomain (let's call it sub.example.com) but for some reason, this always redirects to the first sub domain, i. e. blog.example.com.

I have a `.conf` file for each of my subdomains inside my `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory, they have all been enabled using `a2ensite` and the `default.conf` has been disabled using `a2disconf`. I have also set up the appropriate A records.

I saw a few different people say that adding `NameVirtualHost` would fix this issue, but it seems to be deprecated and without any function.

My `.conf` files look as follows, wherein `example.com` is my actual domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName blog.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =blog.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

The config for my other subdomain looks exactly the same, but with the `DocumentRoot`, `ServerName` and `RewriteCond` changed to reflect its different location and name.
Restarting either the server itself or Apache2 (and waiting a few days, in case setting the A record correctly took a while) doesn't seem to have done anything either.

None of the things I looked up online seem to have had the same problem as I did; I did find a few, but those said it could be mitigated with the `<NameVirtualHost>` directive, which in my case did not do anything.

I'm unfortunately still pretty new to Apache2, so I would appreciate it if anyone here has any idea on how to get this working correctly.

Thank you in advance!

Regards,
Marvin

Comment: Hi - i would suggest running "httpd -S" to show what virtual hosts and names/aliases httpd thinks it has configured.  I might also suggest you use differently names log files so that you can determine which virtual host is getting accessed, by entry in appropriate log

Comment: Hello @Dazed, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it seems that `httpd` is not installed on my server, as running the command you provided results in a `Command not found`; I have also tried manually searching for the binary, but to not avail. Do you perhaps have any why that might be?

Comment: My apologies it's probably "apache2 -S" (I'm more familiar with RHEL, which uses "httpd") see <https://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/8/apache2/>

Comment: Thank you @Dazed. Running that command yields `DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot` and `[Tue Apr 14 10:00:34.417000 2020] [core:warn] [pid 15192] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined`.
The error logs don't really show any errors, but there does appear to be a problem with my SSL configuration.

Comment: maybe https://askubuntu.com/q/927355 - some suggestions on that there

Comment: @Dazed, `source /etc/apache2/envvars` seems to have made the error disappear, but the problem of not being able to access my second subdomain unfortunately remains. `sub.example.com` still opens the same thing as `blog.example.com`, even after restarting everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106735/discussion-between-dazed-and-marvin-johanning).

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative suggestion - you don't actually need a separate redirect config for each domain - you can use a wildcard.  This is the virtual host we have defined for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   # This acts as a catchall for subdomains being accessed on HTTP
   # it forces a redirect to HTTPS.

   ServerName vhbootstraphttps.example.com

   ServerAlias *.example.com

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Note: for a wildcard you need to use a `ServerAlias`